# Android: Generate random color on click?

Tags: android, colors, imageview

I have an `ImageView`, in which I am programmaticly creating drawables and presenting them to the user. My goal is to click on said `ImageView` and change the drawable's color.

How would I go about the random color changing bit? I am currently tinkering with `Random()`, `Color.argb()` and a few other things, but I can't seem to get it to work!

Answer (score 373, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
paint.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
```

or

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Though in your case it seems that you want to create a new drawable and assign it to your view. What is actually the drawable in your case? Is it an image, shape, fill...

Comment: Shouldn't it be 256 instead of 255 everywhere? The API for nextInt() says "Returns a pseudo-random uniformly distributed int in the half-open range [0, n)"

Comment: Kaciula, you are right the n is excluded: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: int color = 0xFF000000 | rnd.nextInt(0xFFFFFF);  " use only 1 random instead of 3"

Comment: Color.argb function requires API at least 26 to work.

Comment: @That'sEnam nope, there are two Color.argb functions, one takes int arguments and has existed since API level 1, the one you are talking about takes float arguments and yes, is only since API 26

Answer (score 23):

So if you’re looking for a beautiful color palette, Maybe It's Not Such A Great Idea To use totally random values.
This approach might not yield the best results, It always ends up with a selection of similar colors that way too dark or way too bright.

### Semi-random approach (Java):

If you need some fresh and shiny colors then use the following simple class, that I wrote previously when I had the same issues. It's **`semi-random`** and uses a predefined color palette:

```
class RandomColors {
    private Stack<Integer> recycle, colors;

    public RandomColors() {
        colors = new Stack<>();
        recycle =new Stack<>();
        recycle.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                0xfff44336,0xffe91e63,0xff9c27b0,0xff673ab7,
                0xff3f51b5,0xff2196f3,0xff03a9f4,0xff00bcd4,
                0xff009688,0xff4caf50,0xff8bc34a,0xffcddc39,
                0xffffeb3b,0xffffc107,0xffff9800,0xffff5722,
                0xff795548,0xff9e9e9e,0xff607d8b,0xff333333
                )
        );
    }

    public int getColor() {
        if (colors.size()==0) {
            while(!recycle.isEmpty())
                colors.push(recycle.pop());
            Collections.shuffle(colors);
        }
        Integer c= colors.pop();
        recycle.push(c);
        return c;
    }
}
```

[image: Random Color Generator class for android]

### Random approach (Java):

But if you're still considering use **`random approach`** you may want use this single line instead of multiple lines of code :

```
int color= ((int)(Math.random()*16777215)) | (0xFF << 24);
```

[image: Random Color Generator android]

The purpose of using this `(0xFF << 24)` is to set the alpha value to the maximum that means zero transparency.

### semi-random (Kotlin)

```
class RandomColors() {
    private val recycle:Stack<Int> = Stack()
    private val colors:Stack<Int> = Stack()
    init {
        recycle.addAll(
            Arrays.asList(
                // ARGB hex to int >> (0xFFEE5670.toInt(),...)
                -0xbbcca, -0x16e19d, -0x63d850, -0x98c549,  
                -0xc0ae4b, -0xde690d, -0xfc560c, -0xff432c,
                -0xff6978, -0xb350b0, -0x743cb6, -0x3223c7,
                -0x14c5, -0x3ef9, -0x6800, -0xa8de,
                -0x86aab8, -0x616162, -0x9f8275, -0xcccccd
            )
        )
    }

    fun getColor(): Int {
        if (colors.size == 0)
            while (!recycle.isEmpty()) colors.push(recycle.pop())
            Collections.shuffle(colors)
        val c = colors.pop()
        recycle.push(c)
        return c
    }
}
```

### Random approach (Kotlin):

```
val color = (Math.random() * 16777215).toInt() or (0xFF shl 24)
```

### Random approach (Compose):

```
fun randomColor(alpha:Int=255) = Color(
    Random.nextInt(256),
    Random.nextInt(256),
    Random.nextInt(256),
    alpha = alpha)
```

preferentially :

```
val randomColor
    get() = Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256))
```

Comment: Yours is the best for a controlled design case ;-)

Answer (score 20):

to get random color values you can use this method:

```
public int getRandomColor(){
   Random rnd = new Random();
   return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
}
```

then apply to your views:

```
myView.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin:

```
val rnd = Random()
val color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))
myView.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

Comment: make sure to import Random from `java.util`

Answer (score 5):

I met this and this is my code,May some help

```
 /**
 * view-source:http://www.kareno.org/js/colors/ 参考
 *Get Random background color and the text color for the background
 * @return 0--》background
 *          1--》text color
 */
public static  int[] getRandomColor() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int RGB = 0xff + 1;
    int[] colors = new int[2];
    int a = 256;
    int r1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * RGB);
    int r2 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * RGB);
    int r3 = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * RGB);
    colors[0] = Color.rgb(r1, r2, r3);
    if((r1 + r2 + r3) > 450) {
        colors[1] = Color.parseColor("#222222");
    }else{
        colors[1] = Color.parseColor("#ffffff");
    }
    return colors;
}
```

Comment: and where is the rgb method ?

Comment: @twntee rgb is a static method see: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#rgb(int, int, int)]

Comment: yup got that ! actually there was multiple imports in my file with save name ?

Answer (score 5):

```
thing.setBackgroundColor(new Random().nextInt());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ColorGenerator for picking the random color

```
ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT

int color1 = generator.getRandomColor();      // generate random color
```

If you want to have the same specific color code for repeated same usernames. you can use like below

```
public int getColorCode(String userName)
    {
        ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
        // generate color based on a key (same key returns the same color), useful for list/grid views
        int colorCode = generator.getColor(userName);

        return colorCode;
    }
```

Comment: what library is ColorGenerator from?

Comment: It's defualy available in android package itself.

Comment: Its not in the current android versio, or in the material3 library

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension to do the same:

```
fun Int.Companion.randomColor(): Int
{
    return Color.argb(255,
                      Random.nextInt(256),
                      Random.nextInt(256),
                      Random.nextInt(256))
}
```

and this is the usage:

```
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Int.randomColor());
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest Sol... Change the range to avoid dark or light color.. like 30 to 200 to avoid black and white family..

```
val randomColor: Int
    get() {
        return Color.rgb((30..200).random(),(30..200).random(),(30..200).random())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code I used in an application, it may help you.

It generates a random color on touch

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            float w = v.getWidth();

            if(x < (w * (1.0/3) )){
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,x,y));
            }else if(x < (w * (2.0 / 3))){
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(x,255,y));
            }else{
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(x,y,255));
            }
            return true;
   }
```

Comment: What exactly does this do? It looks like it's meant to factor in the position of the touch

Comment: it will change the background of view on touch,  when you touch and move, it will generate random color according to x y position and apply to view

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int randomColor(){
    float[] TEMP_HSL = new float[]{0, 0, 0};
    float[] hsl = TEMP_HSL;
    hsl[0] = (float) (Math.random() * 360);
    hsl[1] = (float) (40 + (Math.random() * 60));
    hsl[2] = (float) (40 + (Math.random() * 60));
    return ColorUtils.HSLToColor(hsl);
}
```

Comment: This code generate Blue multiple time , its not random

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following two solutions may help you.

There are two way to get random colors programmatically to set to `view`

**1.First solution**

```
public int randomColor()
       {
         Random random= new Random();
         return Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), 
         random.nextInt(256));
       }
```

> If you are using in `adapter` on scroll you may get random colors for the same `view` this may not look good, to avoid this you can use the second solution.

**2.Second Solution**

> You can use `ColorGenerator.DEFAULT` instead of `ColorGenerator.MATERIAL` as per your choice. You can also use any `number` instead of `position`

```
 ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; 
    int color = generator.getColor(position);
    holder.mEvent_color_strip.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: what's that ColorGenerator? Where do you get it from?

Comment: where do you get ColorGenerator from?

Answer (score 1):

Random color in Jetpack Compose

```
val RandomColor
    get() = Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bb.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(
    getRandomInteger(0,255),
    getRandomInteger(0, 255),
    getRandomInteger(0, 255)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Accurate Solution of this problem:

-First, add this in the gradle (app),

```
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd.randomcolor:library:1.0.0'
```

then compile and rebuild the app.

-The second step just use it by this way,

```
RandomColor randomColor = new RandomColor();

Button l = findviewbyid(R.id.B1);
l.setBackgroundColor(randomColor.randomColor());
```

Reference Link:

> https://github.com/lzyzsd/AndroidRandomColor

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should do like here, it's work to me

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WeatherMainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    holder.date.setText(items.get(position).getDt_txt());
    holder.temp.setText(items.get(position).main.getTemp());
    holder.press.setText(items.get(position).main.getPressure());
    holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String rndColor()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num = random.nextInt(16777215);
        String hex = "";
        while (num != 0)
        {
            if (num % 16 < 10)
                hex = Integer.toString(num % 16) + hex;
            else
                hex = (char)((num % 16)+55) + hex;
            num = num / 16;
        }

        return "#"+((hex.length()<6)?String.format("%0"+(6-hex.length())+"d", 0):"") + hex;
    }
```