# Make Android App (Random Colors)

Tags: java, android

What I need to do is an application that when you click on the screen it will just show random colours on the screen; press the screen again and you will get other random colours  (colours that are not only Red, Blue, Green).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280367/android-generate-random-color-on-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only bright, saturated colors, use `Color.HSVToColor()` instead of setting R, G and B components directrly:

```
float[] hsvColor = {0, 1, 1};
// randomly generate only hue component,
// leaving saturation and brightness maximum possible
hsvColor[0] = new Random().nextFloat() * 360;
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsvColor));
```