# how to set text color randomly in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

```
Random myColor = new Random();
tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(myColor.nextInt(255), myColor.nextInt(255), myColor.nextInt(255)));
```

string.xml:

```
<TextView
           android:id="@+id/score"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Score"
           android:textColor="@color/yellow"
/>
```

This will loop, I want every `score` text has different color. But its not working

Comment: Do the answers in this SO post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280367/android-generate-random-color-on-click

Comment: what's not working ?

Comment: Don't do this, you will not be able to see text if it's the same color as the background. Rather make a list of predefined and select one randomly form the list

Answer (score 0):

You have to get numbers from 0 to 255, so generate a method to get this numbers in order to clean your code:

```
private int getN() {
    return (int) Math.random() * 255;
}
```

And the set the randomized color to your `tv`...

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(getN(), getN(), getN()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):**

```
Random rand = new Random();
Color color = new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat());
```

---

Then:

```
tv.setTextColor(color);
```