# Android: Creating contact thumbnail from name initials

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, thumbnails, bitmapimage

I've an Android `ListView` containing some emails. Some of them have contact thumbnails while some of them don't. For unknown contact thumbnails, I want to create a Bitmap, containing the initials of the corresponding email id. How can I achieve that? I've seen some Android apps using this technique to display contact thumbnail like this:

[image]

To start with, I'm using the following code:

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    view.draw(c);
    iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Where the TextView holds a simple string. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can anyone please give me some pointers? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you're on the right track.
Try it something like this.

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
c.drawText(initials,x,y,paint);
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

You should create your own logic to center the text. You could use some of the following helper method [Paint.getTextSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextSize%28%29) to find out how much space the text needs.

Comment: what is `paint` in this line `c.drawText(initials,x,y,paint);`

Comment: what is paint ??

Answer (score 1):

Simple using this library, you can try it :D

https://github.com/fahmisdk6/AvatarView

this code in your XML File

```
<me.fahmisdk6.avatarview.AvatarView
            android:id="@+id/avatar_user5"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:avCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:avBgTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:avTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:avTextSize="10sp"
            app:avFont="font/avenir_black.ttf"/>
```

And this in Java File

```
AvatarView avatarView5 = (AvatarView) findViewById(R.id.avatar_user5);
avatarView5.bind("Fahmi Sidik", "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/10940190?v=3&s=460");
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564031/12597071) answer.He has used excellent strategy of using button instead of creating bitmap. Coupled with this you can try to select from a set of colors(for background and text), try to use material design guidelines.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334738/12597071) answer has explained how to do so.