# how to make thumbnail image with initials two char from name android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, thumbnails

I want to thumbnail initials with two word for my image view like "Peter Parker" but am able to get only one word "P"while running code how can get second word after space my code is.

```
  holder.imgName?.text=teamData[position].userImage.substring(0,1)
```

Comment: Refer to this link, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181091/10396176

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it functional way:

```
val peterParker = "Peter Parker"

val initials = peterParker
        .split(' ')
        .mapNotNull { it.firstOrNull()?.toString() }                     
        .reduce { acc, s -> acc + s }

println(initials) //PP
```

This would cover cases when a person's name consists of more than 2 words.

Comment: we have two options here one is to use Reduce and Second is to Use Fold.
Reduce will take first element/index of array as accumulated value(incremental,stringbuilder,counter etc ) , where for fold ,we have to pass a default value . moreover mapNotnull will return array of non null value.

Comment: is there any way we can add filter or break point to it.?
like do not show more than two initials?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi sure, just add `.take(2)` after `mapNotNull`

Comment: I think there should be a notBlank check too just to handle empty strings. Faced myself so thought of sharing it here. BTW thanks for the above function helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I have done some Trick & implemented this avatar with a Button lol ;p

create **profile_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <corners
        android:radius="500dp"/>
</shape>
```

then **main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4300313A"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:onClick="clicked"
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="65sp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_bg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:hint="Enter your name"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="clicked"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:text="Submit Name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtname"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then in **MainActivity.java** (to split the string and get the first letter of each word ~ name in if condition with stringbuilder)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText editText;
        Button button;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.avatar);

        }

        public void clicked(View view) {

            String str = editText.getText().toString();

            String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

//First name
            if (strArray.length > 0){
                builder.append(strArray[0], 0, 1);
            }
//Middle name
            if (strArray.length > 1){
                builder.append(strArray[1], 0, 1);
            }
//Surname
            if (strArray.length > 2){
                builder.append(strArray[2], 0, 1);
            }

            button.setText(builder.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can using following way

```
String str = "FirstWord SecondWOrd";
        String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (strArray.length > 0)
            builder.append(strArray[0], 0, 1);
        if (strArray.length > 1)
            builder.append(strArray[1], 0, 1);
        Log.d("New Text" , builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

it look's like your using substring to only grab the letters from position 0 to position 1, This is P in Petter

```
holder.imgName?.text=teamData[position].userImage
```

**.substring(0,1)**

If you'd like to grab the words Petter Parker, you have a few options.
• IndexOf & Substring  - find the position of a string and get the subtext after.
• Substring -  Subtext of string based on parameters

If you plan to change the text length at any stage, you'll need to find the start of the word ( `int start = yourString.indexOf("Petter")`);
and end of the word   ( `int end = yourString.indexOf(" "`))

IndexOf will return the position of the first letter in your query - Your case it's P in Petter --- So    start+"petter".length()

Here's an example of a barcode price checker app I'm working on

```
                    // STRING  FORMAT 00000899999:0.99   

                    String currentLine = "00000899999:0.99";
                    int breakPoint = currentLine.indexOf(":");
                    int end = currentLine.length();
                    int start = breakPoint + 1;
                    String Price = currentLine.substring(start,end);
```

Price will be starting after (:) With +1 or include (:) with no + 1  and end at the lines length.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension function in Kotlin to get initials for a name. You can use a custom view and use draw text and clip shape you want for avatar view.

```
val initials = "Vikas Patidar".asInitials()

fun String.asInitials(limit: Int = 2): String {
    val buffer = StringBuffer()
    trim().split(" ").filter {
        it.isNotEmpty()
    }.joinTo(
        buffer = buffer,
        limit = limit,
        separator = "",
        truncated = "",
    ) { s ->
        s.first().uppercase()
    }
    return buffer.toString()
}
```