# Card view rendom color like above image in android studio

Tags: android, colors, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

[image]

Card view random color like above image in android studio. if more card item than continue  color  sequence

Comment: This will generate random color code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280367/android-generate-random-color-on-click so you can assign that color code to the card

Comment: it's work @Surya Bondada

Comment: @ Payal Sorathiya welcome. you can vote for my comment now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define colours of your choice like these in colors.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
    <item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
    <item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>

    <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/purple</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/orange</item>
        <item>@color/red</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

To randomise selection of colours you could use the following code:
`int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
view.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);`